# Zend Framework: Dynamic content based on Pincodes / Zipcodes

Tags: zend-framework

This seems like a challenge to me! I need to display dynamic content for different pincodes / zipcodes. So the way zend works with url is controller/action if i am not wrong!

Usually user will be selecting the pincodes / zipcodes by clicking on the anchor tag. So how do i create the logic to implement this. Obviously creating different pincode / zipcode controllers and actions and respective views is a bad idea.

what is the best way you would recommend me? Please forgive me if its unclear. I will try to give more info if needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might pass the pincodes/zipcodes in the URL as parameters to your action. For instance, you could have something like:

```
<a href="http://yourhost/yourcontroller/youraction/zipcode/12345">12345</a>
```

And then, inside your controller, you can get the value of the parameter like that:

```
public function youractionAction()
{
    $zipcode = $this->_getParam('zipcode', '');

    //
    // Generate the dynamic content based on the value of the zip code...
    //
}
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: Ya your approach is correct. But i need the url to be like this 
<a href="http://yourhost/california/alpine/91901/">91901</a>. This is for SEO purpose so only. I hope you got what i am saying here. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, you'll probably need to craft a route manually. You can refer to the Zend_Controller_Router documentation here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html